# Tuple has no object for high scores?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a high scores list where you can add your own score. This is the code I've got:

```
elif choice == "2":
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    score = int(input("What score did you get? "))
    entry = (score, name)
    scores.append(entry)
    scores.sort(reverse=True)
    scores = scores[:10]
```

But this comes up with:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

What do I need to change to get it to work?

Comment: your Error is very clear 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append' !!! use a list instead !

Comment: `scores.append` means that `scores` is a `tuple`. Make it a list -> problem solved.

Comment: Please can someone help with what the code would be for the list. First time using python and can't figure it out

Comment: @vaultah : It's ok for `entry` to be a tuple. But `scores` needs to be a list of tuples, not a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, and as such, have no append. Use lists instead.

Comment: What do I change in the code for a list though? Sorry I'm very new to this

Comment: @user4308409: It's not easy for us to tell you how to change stuff in code you haven't shown us. There are a couple of ways to create a tuple, and if we just try to guess what you've done and base our instructions on that then we'll probably just confuse you further. So paste the part of your program that creates the `scores` tuple into your question and we'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @user4308409 Change the part that assigns to `scores`. Assign a list instead of a tuple. As PM 2Ring notes, you don't show that code, so I can give you no more specific guidance. In any case, SO isn't for mentoring. If you don't know what a list and a tuple are, read a tutorial or the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, somewhere you define scores to be a tuple. I.e.

```
scores = ()
```

or

```
scores = tuple(scores)
```

Scores should be a list, like this:

```
scores = []
```

Specially since you not only want to append values to it but also sort it (scores.sort will also fail)

As others have pointed out, for us to be able to give you a correct answer we would need to see more of the code.

Welcome to Stackoverflow btw!